# How to only keep X number of duplicates within an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, duplicates

I am trying to only keep a maximum of 8 duplicates within an array. I have found through S.O. questions how to filter duplicates from an array, but I dont know how to keep up to 8 of them within the array. 
Any idea how to achieve this ?

Here are the codes I am using to filter duplicates:

```
func removeDuplicates(array: [String]) -> [String] {
    var encountered = Set<String>()
    var result: [String] = []
    for value in array {
        if encountered.contains(value) {
            // Do not add a duplicate element.
        }
        else {
            // Add value to the set.
            encountered.insert(value)
            // ... Append the value.
            result.append(value)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

I wish to count how many duplicates, and if <= some chosen number, to keep them.

Comment: Don't use a encountered Set but a Map saving the times you encountered a specific element.

Comment: Or use an NSCountedSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend putting this in an Array extension, so it can work for any kind of contents — Ints, Strings, custom objects, whatever.

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable
{
    /// Returns a copy of `self` with at most `maxOccurrences` occurrences of any element.
    @warn_unused_result
    func removeDuplicates(maxOccurrences maxOccurrences: Int = 1) -> [Element]
    {
        var result: [Element] = []
        var occurrences: [Element: Int] = [:]
        for value in self {
            let count = occurrences[value] ?? 0
            if count >= maxOccurrences { continue }
            result.append(value)
            occurrences[value] = count + 1
        }
        return result
    }
}

var a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
a.removeDuplicates(maxOccurrences: 0)  // empty
a.removeDuplicates()                   // 1, 2, 3
a.removeDuplicates(maxOccurrences: 2)  // 1, 2, 2, 3, 3
a.removeDuplicates(maxOccurrences: 3)  // 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer. I had to select the first response. But works great.

Comment: Actually, it doesnt work. I am getting errors. For the first extension, and "Type T does not conform to protocol Hashable. I would prefer to go with the hashable way; much more flexible. if it works, i ll edit !

Comment: @jim you simply need to make your type conform to [Hashable](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Hashable_Protocol/index.html). String already does this. You can copy/paste my code into a playground and see that it works for Ints, but it also works for Strings :)

Comment: I am now dealing with [[String]]. I am in the playground, and I get several errors immediately after pasting. First is saying that the statement cannot begin with a closure expression.

Comment: @jim ah, I see — my code is for Swift 2 (Xcode 7) but it sounds like you are using Swift 1. I would recommend upgrading ASAP! As for `[String]`, that's tricky because computing the hash of an array can be expensive. NSArray defines its hash as just `count`, which is a very bad but very fast hash function. It's up to you to decide how you want to handle this. You could also adapt the approach to not require Hashable, but then you wouldn't be able to use a Dictionary for storage of `occurrences`, so you would probably have to do O(n) comparisons at each step which is very expensive.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for the advices and the time.

Answer (score 1):

Two similar solutions - one with my original idea of a map / dictionary and the second one with Paulw11's idea of a counted set

```
func removeDuplicates(array: [String], times:Int) -> [String] {
    var encountered = [String:Int]()
    var result = [String]()
    for value in array {
        let time = encountered[value] ?? 0
        if time < times {
            encountered[value] = time + 1
            result.append(value)
        }
    }
    return result
}

func removeDuplicates2(array: [String], times:Int) -> [String] {
    let encountered = NSCountedSet()
    var result = [String]()
    for value in array {
        encountered.addObject(value)
        if encountered.countForObject(value) <= times {
            result.append(value)
        }
    }
    return result
}

print(removeDuplicates(["", "1", "", "", "1", "1"], times: 2))
print(removeDuplicates2(["", "1", "", "", "1", "1"], times: 2))
```

Output

> ["", "1", "", "1"]
>   ["", "1", "", "1"]

Comment: You rock ! Thank you very much.